# why my custom method in controller return undefined method for nil:NilClass mosf of the time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i'm practically new on rails and having a problem.

I made a custom method for handling index controller so i could trigger create but in return i always get nil for nil class no matter what the attribute is even though in the instance variable returns value.

i did try change the method using restful rails 'create' but still return the same thing.

and the weirdest thing is....sometimes it works.

what should i do?

thanks in advance.

Here are my codes:

**setup_controller**

```
skip_before_filter :authorize

def index
    @countries = Country.all(:order => 'iso_code')
    @users = User.all
    @company = Company.new
end

def create_company
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    if @company.save!
        @company.create_uoms
        @company.create_product_statuses
        redirect_to login_path #default_uom_setup_path(company: @company)
        flash[:notice] = "Thank you. Please login to proceed"
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Error creating company.  Please try again."
        redirect_to :controller => 'setup', :action => 'index'
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
 <h3>Please Enter the New Company Details</h3>

<%= form_for :company, :url => {:controller => 'setup', :action => 'create_company', :method => 'post'}, :html=>{:multipart=>true} do |form| %>
<table>
    <tr><td>Name        </td>   <td><%= form.text_field :name %>                                                </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address 1   </td>   <td><%= form.text_field :address_1 %>                                           </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address 2   </td>   <td><%= form.text_field :address_2 %>                                           </td></tr>
    <tr><td>City        </td>   <td><%= form.text_field :city %>                                                </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Country     </td>   <td><%= form.select :country_id, @countries.collect {|c| [c.iso_code, c.id] } %>    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Logo File   </td>   <td><%= form.file_field :logo_filename %>                                       </td></tr>
</table>
<%= submit_tag "Create Companies" %>         
<% end %>
```

**routes**

```
  resources :setup do
    collection do
      post 'create_company'
      get  '/:company/default_uom_setup', to: 'setup#default_uom_setup', as: "default_uom"
      get  '/:company/create_warehouses', to: 'setup#create_warehouses', as: "create_warehouses"
    end
  end
```

**Company.erb**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :country
  has_many  :warehouses
  has_many  :products
  has_many  :customers
  has_many  :customer_types 
  has_many  :purchase_order_types
  has_many  :purchase_orders
  has_many  :receipt_types
  has_many  :orders
  has_many  :order_types
  has_many  :product_statuses
  has_many  :product_categories
  has_many  :suppliers
  has_many  :uoms
  has_many  :assignment_types
  has_many  :product_subcategories
  has_many  :volume_uoms
  has_many  :quantity_uoms
  has_many  :weight_uoms
  has_many  :dimension_uoms  

  validates :name, uniqueness: true
  validates :name, :address_1, :city, :country_id, presence: true

  def default_quantity_uom
    @default_quantity_uom = QuantityUom.find(self.default_quantity_uom_id)
  end

  def default_weight_uom
    @default_weight_uom = WeightUom.find(self.default_weight_uom_id)
  end

  def default_length_uom
    @default_length_uom = DimensionUom.find(self.default_length_uom_id)
  end

  def create_uoms
    quantity_uoms = QuantityUom.create([  {code: "EACH",  description: "Each",  name: "Each",       discrete: true, company_id: self.id},
                                              {code: "CASE",  description: "Case",  name: "Case",       discrete: true, company_id: self.id},
                                              {code: "PALT",  description: "Pallet",    name: "Pallet",     discrete: true, company_id: self.id},
                                                  {code: "UNIT",  description: "Unit",  name: "Unit",       discrete: true, company_id: self.id}])  

    dimension_uoms = DimensionUom.create([{code: "M", description:  "Meter",    name: "Meter",  discrete: true,  company_id: self.id},
                                              {code: "FT", description:  "Foot",    name: "Foot",     discrete: true,  company_id: self.id},
                                              {code: "IN", description:  "Inch",    name: "Inch",     discrete: true,  company_id: self.id}])

    weight_uoms = WeightUom.create([{code: "LP", description: "Pound",      name: "Pound",    discrete: true,  company_id: self.id},
                                      {code: "KG", description: "Kilogram",     name: "Kilogram",   discrete: true,  company_id: self.id}])

     volume_uoms = VolumeUom.create([ {code: "M3",    description: "Cubic Meter",  name: "Cu M",  discrete: true,  company_id: self.id},
                                        {code: "FT3",    description: "Cubic Foot",  name: "Cu Ft", discrete: true,  company_id: self.id},
                                        {code: "I3",    description: "Cubic Inch",  name: "Cu In",  discrete: true,  company_id: self.id}])
  end


  def create_product_statuses
    product_statuses = ProductStatus.create([
      {code: "AV", description: "Available",      allocatable: true,   company_id: self.id  },
      {code: "DM", description: "Damaged",        allocatable: false,  company_id: self.id  },
      {code: "HD", description: "On-Hold",        allocatable: false,  company_id: self.id  },
      {code: "QA", description: "Quality Audit",  allocatable: false,  company_id: self.id  }])
  end


end
```

**ERROR**

```
Started POST "/setup/create_company" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-14 17:23:23 +0700
Processing by SetupController#create_company as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"23batLaNe7Z1Xa17PsrDS/av26J/zkLnw3QN15/y6ic=", "company"=>{"name"=>"fdsfsdf", "address_1"=>"asdfasdfasdf", "address_2"=>"asdfasdfasdfadsfasd", "city"=>"asdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfdas", "country_id"=>"1", "logo_filename"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb3c14838 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20130814-11385-18dve10>, @original_filename="Domikado.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"company[logo_filename]\"; filename=\"Domikado.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Companies"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Company Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = BINARY 'fdsfsdf' LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass:
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:50:in `block in initialize'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:52:in `block in initialize'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:52:in `block in initialize'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:52:in `block in initialize'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:52:in `block in initialize'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:128:in `accept'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:480:in `block in dump_ivars'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:478:in `dump_ivars'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:150:in `visit_Object'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:128:in `accept'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:92:in `push'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:244:in `dump'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:39:in `quote'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:246:in `quote'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:14:in `block in to_sql'
  (gem) arel-4.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/bind_visitor.rb:26:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_BindParam'
  (gem) arel-4.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
  (gem) arel-4.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:160:in `block in visit_Arel_Nodes_Values'
  (gem) arel-4.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:158:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_Values'
  (gem) arel-4.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
  (gem) arel-4.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:123:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_InsertStatement'
  (gem) arel-4.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
  (gem) arel-4.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
  (gem) arel-4.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:68:in `accept'
  (gem) arel-4.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/bind_visitor.rb:11:in `accept'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:13:in `to_sql'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:95:in `insert'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:76:in `insert'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:498:in `create_record'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:78:in `create_record'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:303:in `block in create_record'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__594700878__create__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:303:in `create_record'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create_record'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:466:in `create_or_update'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:299:in `block in create_or_update'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:393:in `_run__594700878__save__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:299:in `create_or_update'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:128:in `save!'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:41:in `save!'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `block in save!'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `save!'
  app/controllers/setup_controller.rb:13:in `create_company'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__788419911__process_action__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  (gem) rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  (gem) activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__56629178__call__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.8.0/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.8.0/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.8.0/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  (gem) railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  (gem) railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  (gem) railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  (gem) railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  (gem) railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/googs/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Paste your error message with backtrace.

Comment: please post the full error message.

Comment: I'm sorry since i'm new i don't know how to use backtrace..i copy paste it from the terminal..

Comment: what is your company_params? and give please code of your model Company too

Comment: :name,
                     :address_1, 
                                    :address_2, :city, 
                                    :postal_code, 
                                    :country_id, 
                                    :logo_filename,
                                    :default_quantity_uom_id,
                                    :default_length_uom_id,
                                    :default_weight_uom_id)

Comment: i'm using strong parameter for company params..for the model company i already update it again